# Is there a cleaner way to write this jQuery dropdown code?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function (below) which works fine. It's for a dropdown button that is triggered on a click event. I'm looking for a way to clean up the code and make it much simpler. Thanks.

jQuery

```js
$("#dropbtn1").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content1").toggleClass("show-dropdown");
  $(".dropdown-content2, .dropdown-content3").removeClass("show-dropdown");

});

$("#dropbtn2").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content2").toggleClass("show-dropdown");
  $(".dropdown-content1, .dropdown-content3").removeClass("show-dropdown");

});

$("#dropbtn3").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content3").toggleClass("show-dropdown");
  $(".dropdown-content1, .dropdown-content2").removeClass("show-dropdown");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><button id="dropbtn1" type="button">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="menu dropdown-content1">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li><button id="dropbtn2" type="button">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="menu dropdown-content2">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li><button id="dropbtn3" type="button">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="menu dropdown-content3">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an event listener on a jQuery list containing all your buttons.
Then close their menu sibling, and open the concerned one.

```js
$('.dropdown > li > button').click(function() {
  const jSiblingMenus = $(this).siblings('.menu'),
    isAlreadyOpened = jSiblingMenus.css('display') !== 'none';
  
  $('.dropdown > li > .menu').hide();
  
  (isAlreadyOpened) ? jSiblingMenus.hide() : jSiblingMenus.show();
});
```

```css
.dropdown > li > .menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown">
  <li>
    <button type="button">Dropdown</button>
    
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button type="button">Dropdown</button>
    
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button type="button">Dropdown</button>
    
    <div class="menu dropdown-content">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to each drop down button and change code to

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><button id="dropbtn1" type="button" class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="menu dropdown-content1">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li><button id="dropbtn2" type="button" class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="menu dropdown-content2">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li><button id="dropbtn3" type="button" class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="menu dropdown-content3">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

and then you can write js as

```
  $(".drop-btn").click (function() {
    $(".menu").hide();
    $(this).siblings('.menu').toggle();
  });
```

and a little css

```
.menu{
  display:none;
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/uj4oa5rL/1/)

## UPDATE

```
  $(".drop-btn").click (function() {
    $(this).siblings('.menu').toggle();
  });
```

Remove `$('.menu').hide()` to make user toggle work as per your requirment. Check this [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/uj4oa5rL/4/)

Comment: Works, but I want the user click on the button again to toggle the children on or off. Currently, I have to click on another button to turn the previous one off. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @user22768 i have update the fiddle. See this https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/uj4oa5rL/8/

Comment: @user22768 Hope this works. Please accept this as answer.

Comment: It works, but I have all three dropdown showing at the same time which is not what I wanted. @iArcadia's code below does exactly what I want it to do. I'm still grateful for your help. Thanks!

Comment: @fridayikon i have given you code to open one dropdown at a time. Also open multiple drop down at a time. Both didn't met your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

On click you can remove class "show-dropdown" for all divs that have a class starting with "dropdown-content" (may be you add another class which all these share) and afterwards toggle "show-dropdown" to the current related node.